# CSS: Sizing section's inside elements in two evenly

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

Within my body, I have two sections on top of each other in a column (all flex boxes). They will have the same properties, therefore I used the same ID. Only difference is one section will have the image displayed left of text, the other will display image right.

I have an image placed next to a div with text inside (H2 & p). I want the image and div to split the section flex box width evenly. I tried declaring an image/div width but it won't resize either. Any help here?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!--Part 5-->
    <section id="splitscreen">
        <img src="/Images/white-hat.jpg"/>
        <section>
            <div>
                <h2>Part 1</h2>
                <p>some other text</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>

<!--Part 6-->
    <section id="splitscreen">
        <section>
            <div>
                <h2>Part 2</h2>
                <p>More Text</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <img src="/Images/guaranteedseal.png"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/*=====Part 5/6=====*/

#splitscreen{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    margin: 25px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 5vh;
}

#splitscreen img{
    width = 30vw;
}
```

[What I Have Now. Refer to http:www.graphicdisorder.com sections Concepts/Stickers. I'm attempting to mimic this layout](http://www.graphicdisorder.com)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like they mentioned above ID's are supposed to be used for unique instances... only one tag... classes for multiple "groupings" of tags.

Let me know if this works for you?

[Here is the **JSFiddle** Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcnkn4mj/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5374c22ee4b0297decd522a5/t/537dcd58e4b007df5118ebf1/1400753542400/1.jpg?format=500w"/>
        <div class="txt">
            <h2>Part 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="txt">
            <h2>Part 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5374c22ee4b0297decd522a5/t/55785b78e4b06b397737c826/1433951097309/?format=500w"/>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
.container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.txt{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    text-align: center;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    max-width: 200px;

}
img{
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. I played with the sizing and margins and got what I was looking for. Thank You!

Comment: @blackRob4953 cool cool. yea no problem man, hit me next time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you mistake the usage of similar `id` (Identifier), it must be just one in whole document. It's like a person, there are no identical and what they look like similar it's to show that they are similar you should use `class`.

```
<section class="splitscreen">
</section>

.splitscreen img{
    width = 30vw;
}
```

What about your question, here you need using `float`. I will explain on "left image" example.

Firstly, create `<section>` which wrapped by another one and input inside wrapper image, like this:

```
<section class="splitscreen">
    <section class="floated-left">
         <img src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg"/>
    </section>
</section>
```

Next put you text inside first `section` after wrapped `section`

```
<section class="splitscreen">
    <section class="floated-left"><img src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg"/></section>
    <h2>Part 1</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>
```

And let's style it!

```
.splitscreen {
    width: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.floated-left {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
}

.floated-left > img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Here we take a width of all our block: 700px. Next, step float text to left with `float: left;`.  Next is giving to image some `width` in example it's `200px`. And last one it's `margin`, it makes some free space between image and text.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eft3gt8h). Let me know if there are any errors. If you have any question, you'r welcome!

```css
.splitscreen {
    width: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.floated-left {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
}

.floated-left > img {
    width: 200px;
}

.floated-right {
    float: right;
    width: 220px;
}

.floated-right > img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="splitscreen">
    <section class="floated-left"><img src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg"/></section>
    <h2>Part 1</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>

<section class="splitscreen">
    <section class="floated-right"><img src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg"/></section>
    <h2>Part 2</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>
```

Comment: I think we're both on the same page here, and your explanation makes sense. However it didn't work, I'll edit the question and add an image showing what I have now. Here a link to the site I am trying to mimic http://www.graphicdisorder.com. Something similar to the concept/stickers section in the middle. I tried inspecting the code to see what they did, but that was unhelpful.

Comment: @blackRob4953 I'm updated the answer, please check it!

Comment: Thanks so much. This wasn't what I was looking for in this question, however I was going to ask this next (Regarding having the text wrap around an image). So thank you for this and the clear explaining! It helped